# User recreating tags that are not required

Tags: discussion

If a specific user with 30k rep has re-created a tag that serves no purpose, and then edited 80 or so questions to 'add' that useless tag, how do we ask him to stop?

Or maybe the question is "should we" ask him to stop? Or do we just let it go.

Basically a certain user made the tag [laravel-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-routing)  - then edited lots of questions themselves to add it to that question.

The thing is following the tag creation rules - there is no need for this tag.

> You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you
>   feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new
>   topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

It serves no real purpose and the topic and knowledge is already covered by the 3 tags:

[laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) 
[laravel-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-3) 
[laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4)

Its not the first time this user has created sub tags relating to laravel (like [laravel-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-model), [laravel-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-auth)) - but they only had 2-3 questions at the time, so they no longer exist. However this time he seems to have made sure its on lots of questions to ensure the tag remains...

Comment: You ask him to stop.  How?  Nicely, I would imagine.  Point them at this meta question.  The issue seems far from clear-cut, however; exactly how is [laravel-routing] a bad tag?

Comment: I didnt say it was a *bad* tag - I said there is *no need* for tag. If  that tag is valid, then we might as well have `[laravel-model]`, `[laravel-queue]`, `[laravel-session]` etc - its a slippy slope to 20 tags that cover each sub-section of Laravel that serve no purpose above what the 3 main tags already serve.

Comment: Much like the objective-c swamp of class-specific tags...

Comment: In all of the questions I looked at, the user didn't just add [laravel-routing], the user *removed* the [routes] and/or [routing] tags. I don't know if the user is right that those tags are inappropriate for such questions, but if they are, then I do think a [laravel-routing] tag is a better choice than simply removing the tags with no replacement.

Comment: Do we have a burnination of routes/routing/route going on?

Comment: @hvd: In the past, the community's consensus was for more specific tags, not tag clusters like [laravel] [routing].  Wish you guys would make up your mind.

Comment: I think the [laravel-routing] tag is useful, and helps in classifying a question much more than [routing] (which is too general). Creating laravel sub-tags should not be considered a problem IMO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey By "I don't know" I really did mean "I don't know". I wasn't trying to give any particular opinion on the removal of the the [routes] and/or [routing] tags, I just wanted to provide some information that the OP may have overlooked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: How do we go about flagging a tag wiki? The routing tag wiki is plagiarized from Wikipedia with no attribution. It's pretty blatant. "This article...". http://stackoverflow.com/tags/routing/info